# Did Harry Wormwood misgender Miss Trunchbull?

Tags: plot-explanation, matilda, matilda-2022

During *Matilda the Musical* (2022), Harry Wormwood describes selling a car made from two wrecked vehicles to "a bear of a man" (scene index 29:52).

Was he referring to the car that he sold to Miss Trunchbull, and did he thusly misgender her as a man, or was he referring to an actual man who is completely unrelated to Miss Trunchbull?

Comment: In the original show-script he misgenders his daughter in every single scene.

Comment: I think that's just a running gag. In the book that the film is based on Matilda had an older brother.

Comment: They wanted a boy. Harry constantly refers to her as his son

Comment: Yes, I'm not sure that these two situations are related.

Answer (score 6):

Going over the source material again it would seem that the musical version omits the scene where Mr Wormwood describes using sawdust to pack out the gear-box of an old car, as well as the scene where Miss Trunchbull describes how she fell for this trick.

With the absence of both of these scenes it appears that the two characters may never have met. Therefore the "bear of a man" isn't Miss Trunchbull.